# error 1084: expecting semicolon before 0

Tags: actionscript-3, shuffle, flash-cs6

I'm little stuck with the following code:

```
    function placeShuffleFishs():void
{
  for (var i:int 0; i<shuffleRoom.length; ++i) //syntax error: expecting semicolon before 0.
  {
   addChild(shuffleRoom[i]);
   shuffleRoom[i].x = int(xValues[i]);
   shuffleRoom[i].y = 80;
  }
}
```

Please let me know how to solve that problem, 
thanks

Comment: You're never setting it. Just like `var foo:String "string";` wouldn't work without an equal sign neither does your `var i:int 0`. Add an equal sign before 0 and it'll work fine.

Comment: ok thanks it work, i forget about "="

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **=**

```
 ...
 for (var i:int      =      0; i<shuffleRoom.length; ++i) 
 ...
```